# Nested node_modules folder disappears after packaging

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm building a test Electron app where I clone an express server repo, with its own `node_modules` folder, into my Electron repo, also with its own `node_modules` folder. The contents of my app looks like this:

```
main.js (starts app and forks process from the express app's index.js)
node_modules
package.json
cloned-express-app
   |
    --node_modules
      index.js
      package.json
```

When I package my app for Mac with `electron-builder` (with or without asar enabled) the inner `node_modules` directory doesn't make it into the packaged app. Is there some magic that Electron is doing to eliminate that folder? Is there some way I can ensure that it gets in?

Here are the contents of my [main.js](https://github.com/bradydowling/electron-server-hello-world/blob/master/main.js) and my [package.json](https://github.com/bradydowling/electron-server-hello-world/blob/master/package.json) in case that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in `electron-builder` that is present after version 20.15.0 and at least up to version 20.26.0. Install `electron-builder@20.15.0` and this issue will be fixed.

Comment: Has this fixed on the latest build ?

Comment: @nish1013 I don't believe so. The release notes don't mention anything and [this issue that I created](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3185) is still open.